# how to getting x,y position from curve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

i want to implement this animation below:

[image]

and i'm create js fiddle to work like that, but i have stack when i want to set a position of (x,y) ..

```
var interval;
function moveit(left,top) {
    $("#obj").css("left",left+'px');
    $("#obj").css("top",top+'px');
}
$("#change").click(function(){
    var left = $("#left").val(); //posisi x
    var top = $("#top").val();  //posisi y
    var velocity= 1;

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        left = parseFloat(left) + parseFloat(velocity);
        top = parseFloat(top) + parseFloat(velocity);
        console.log('position x = ' + left);
        console.log('position y = ' + top);

        if(top >= 400 ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        }

        moveit(left,top);
    },10);
});

$("#clear").click(function(){
clearInterval(interval);
});
​
```

this is my js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/viyancs/MxuRP/1/

**my question**

1. how to getting x,y coordinate  of that  curve by generating code ?
2. maybe you have another idea for make this better?

thanks you

Comment: Your velocity is constant and there is no acceleration, how would you get a projectile motion?

Comment: What is the `computer-science` tag for? I added an `animation` tag, but I don't know if the `computer-science` tag really fits.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I think a `physics` tag may fit though.

Comment: @AlvinWong - True. Feel free to add that; that makes sense.

Comment: @jared Farrish thanks for correct my answer....:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the y-component of the velocity through time.

http://jsfiddle.net/MxuRP/2/

```
var interval;
function moveit(left,top) {
    $("#obj").css("left",left+'px');
    $("#obj").css("top",top+'px');
}
$("#change").click(function(){
    var left = $("#left").val(); //posisi x
    var top = $("#top").val();  //posisi y
    var velocityX = 1;
    var velocityY = 0;
    var accelerationY = 0.1;

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        left = parseFloat(left) + parseFloat(velocityX);
        velocityY += accelerationY;
        top = parseFloat(top) + parseFloat(velocityY);
        console.log('position x = ' + left);
        console.log('position y = ' + top);

        if(top >= 400 ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        }

        moveit(left,top);
    },10);
});

$("#clear").click(function(){
clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: that's cool result...thanks..

i want to ask in another case, i'm have idea to create line like character `S` , can you suggest me what i should do for getting (x,y) of character `S`?...